# ggplot and dplyr filter reference

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is my code:

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(mpg, hp, color=hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "darkorange2", high = "darkred",
                       breaks=c(min(mtcars$hp), max(mtcars$hp)), 
                       labels=c("Min","Max"))
```

What I would like to do is, include the breaks in the `scale_color_gradient` function in the filter I have called beforehand. I know that `.$hp` works in base R and only using the variable name in `dplyr`, but how do I use it in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the plotting code in braces to keep the "right" object in the `.`. Also if you want to go from min to max, you can use `range()`. For example

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  {ggplot(., aes(mpg, hp, color=hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "darkorange2", high = "darkred",
                       breaks=range(.$hp), 
                       labels=c("Min","Max"))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems like a good way to solve this scenario.